# Nested document value search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nested, document

Given the following user object in MongoDB, 
what would be the fastest way to search by `relation.$.status == 'friends'`?

Need to find a way to `find` in a `user` collection's `relation` data that contains an object with a value of `"friends"` (see pseudo query below).

The keys for this particular collection have been set to uids, so assume that the "**User Data**" section below may not be altered.

**User Data:**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('1a1a1a1a111a1a11a1a1a1a'),
    "name": "Tester",
    "relation": {
        "2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b": {
            "status": 'friends',
            "status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
            // etc...
        },
        "3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c": {
            "status": 'engaged',
            "status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
var query = {
    // pseudo, key-ignoring nested document search
    'relation.$.status': 'friends'
}
var projection = {
    'relation': 1
}
db.user.findOne(query, projection)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
{ 
    "2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b": {
       "status": 'friends',
       "status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
       // etc...
    }
}
```

The obvious correction to the *User Data* structure should be making `relation` an array of objects of which contain `_id` and `status` as keys. Kinda looking for a temporary shim here.

Comment: You're right. It will be rather simple, if `relation` property would be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply mongodb [**Map/Reduce**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) technique for this task.

1) **`map`** function will determine nested objects from `relation` object, which contain `status` field equal to `"friends"` value:

```
var map = function () {
    for (var key in this.relation) {
        var relation = this.relation[key];
        if (relation.status == "friends")
            emit(key, relation);
    }
}
```

2) **`reduce`** function will actually do nothing, just return single emitted relation:

```
var reduce = function (key, values) {
    return values[0];
}
```

As a result you'll have collection with such objects:

```
{
  _id: "2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b",
  value: {
    status: "friends",
    status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
    // etc...
  }
}
```

---

If you decide to replace `relation` object with array, you can use [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to construct similar query.

**User Data:**

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("1a1a1a1a111a1a11a1a1a1a"),
    name: "Tester",
    relations: [
        {
            id: "2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b",
            status: "friends",
            status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
            // etc...
        },
        {
            id: "3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c3c",
            status: "engaged",
            status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
            // etc...
        }
    ]
}
```

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$relations" },
    { $match: { "relations.status": "friends" } },
    { $project: _id: 0,
        id: "$relations.id",
        status: "$relations.status",
        status_changed_date: "$relations.status_chaged_date"
        // etc...
    }
])
```

**Output:**

```
{
  id: "2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b2b",
  status: "friends",
  status_changed_date: ISODate("2013-10-28T00:00:00.0000Z"),
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Would this be any faster than just obtaining all the data and using, say, Python to run the map section? The trade off seems to just be putting load on Mongo instead of some other system, right?

Comment: It depends on many factors: system architecture, network and machines speed, etc. You may to test these two approaches, but I believe, if the work could be done in Mongo (and DB in general), it should be done there.

Comment: Also, try to reconsider your db schema and save relations in array (as you mentioned in question). This way you can use aggregation framework for such queries and it will be faster then map/reduce.

Comment: the map function is fine, but your reduce function is terribly wrong.  Unless all you want to get back are just the _id fields with null values.

Comment: Such code for reduce function (i.e. its absence) based on the fact, that there will be exactly one single value per one particular key. In this case MongoDB will not call the reduce function for any key, so it will never execute. But I think, it's really very specific moment, and useless in general.  So, thank you for pointing this out; I've corrected my answer.